# jQuery Mobile - Collapsible List as a header bar item

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to give a "Options" drop down in the header bar. I've successfully added it to the header. But the problem is, it is stretching in its "expand" state, and return to normal in its collapse state.

Here's the fiddle to the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/vNTR5/

I've tried a couple of things :

1. I noticed the "ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed" class in the collapsed state, vs "ui-collapsible-heading" class in the expanded state. I captured the events and tried adding the "ui-collapsible-heading-collapse" class. It resulted in keeping the list permanently "expanded" once it had been expanded.
2. I tried making custom css class, and adding and removing those. But it simply won't take in `margin-left` added through a class. It takes it when its inline.

Please help.

Code snippet:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header"> 

                  <h1>Main Menu</h1>

                  <div data-role="collapsible" id="optionsMenu" data-mini="true" class="rightMenu" data-collapsed-icon="gear" data-expanded-icon="gear">
                    <h3 style="margin-left:-20%;">Options</h3>
                      <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>                        
                      </ul>
                  </div>

             </div>
```

CSS:

```
.rightMenu{
    position: absolute;
    top:-10%;   
    right:2%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/FSSzK/

```
.rightMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top:-10%;   
    right:2%;
    width: 100px !important;
}

.rightMenu .ui-collapsible-content .ui-listview {
    margin: -10px -15px -10px -35px !important;
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! I've noticed that you've written margin values in `px`. Will not work the same way for every screen size I presume. Need to check a workaround for that, maybe write media queries.